# Parsing data from API - Best way to get all data possible?

Tags: python, pandas, api

I am trying to get crash data from https://data.pa.gov/Public-Safety/Crash-Incident-Details-CY-1997-Current-Annual-Coun/dc5b-gebx using there API, with the documentation here. https://dev.socrata.com/docs/paging.html .

When trying to use python to do this I am only able to get the default amount of records, as below.

```
response = requests.get("https://data.pa.gov/resource/dc5b-gebx.json?limit=50000")
data = response.json()
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

When using Limit, the api does not return a value.

I want to return as many values as possible (if not all of them) to do a analysis project with. Bit confused, would appreciate some help here - Thanks!

Comment: Read the api docs properly, you can find more about it. You missed $ in the query param. Refer to below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the api, you are forgetting the '$', you should be requesting

https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/earthquakes.json?$limit=5000.

You can also request more than that, i.e.

https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/earthquakes.json?$limit=100000

But this only returns 10,820 results (not sure if this is the limit or the entire dataset).

(You can just use https://data.pa.gov/resource/dc5b-gebx.json?$limit=5 for your dataset, but this takes much longer to load so I am unsure of the limit)

Comment: Thanks @Dharman. I did this before, the only issue I have found is that the dataset is a lot larger but there is a limit on the request size. I think there might be a way to make multiple requests, looping through from the end of the first one maybe?